# Timesync of virtual server

Tags: server, virtualization, date

I have a Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) virtual server (using virtuozzo) running at a external provider and was not able to get 2-factor-authentification running in my nextcloud instances. I think this is related to the fact that the sever time is behind.

If I get the time with

```
date
```

I receive the correct timezone but the time is ~ 3 minutes behind.

I wanted to resolve this by installing ntp

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
sudo nano /etc/ntp.conf
```

I set up the conf file like this

```
# /etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd; see ntp.conf(5) for help 
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift 

# Time Server 
server de.pool.ntp.org iburst 

# By default, exchange time with everybody, but don't allow configuration. 
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited 
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited 

# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely. 
restrict 127.0.0.1 
restrict ::1
```

I restarted the service

```
sudo systemctl restart ntp.service
```

But the time is still not in sync and with

```
ntpq -p
```

I receive this error message

```
ntpq: read: Connection refused
```

If I sync the time with

```
ntpd -q -g
```

I get

```
11 Apr 17:07:24 ntpd[4967]: ntpd 4.2.8p4@1.3265-o Wed Feb 14 14:56:29 UTC 2018 (1): Starting 
11 Apr 17:07:24 ntpd[4967]: Command line: ntpd -q -g 
11 Apr 17:07:24 ntpd[4967]: proto: precision = 0.089 usec (-23) 
11 Apr 17:07:24 ntpd[4967]: Listen and drop on 0 v6wildcard [::]:123 
11 Apr 17:07:24 ntpd[4967]: Listen and drop on 1 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123 
11 Apr 17:07:24 ntpd[4967]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1:123 
11 Apr 17:07:24 ntpd[4967]: Listen normally on 3 venet0:0 <IP ADRESS> 
11 Apr 17:07:24 ntpd[4967]: Listen normally on 4 lo [::1]:123 
11 Apr 17:07:24 ntpd[4967]: Listen normally on 5 venet0 [2a02:2b80:1:0:5652::625]:123 
11 Apr 17:07:24 ntpd[4967]: Listen normally on 6 venet0 [::2]:123 
11 Apr 17:07:24 ntpd[4967]: Listening on routing socket on fd #23 for interface updates
11 Apr 17:07:31 ntpd[4967]: step-systime: Operation not permitted 
11 Apr 17:07:31 ntpd[4967]: ntpd: time set +170.495454 s ntpd: time set +170.495454s
```

But the time is still 3 minutes behind

What can I do to sync this virtual server? I opened a ticket at the provider but still have no answer.

Comment: You can't sync the time on a Virtuozzo server from a virtual machine (which is actually a container). The hosting provider must set it.

Comment: As @MichaelHampton said currently containers in general have no namespacing for time, so they can't set time at all. Your error on " step-systime" indicates that. All containers use the time of the host.